# Yahoo Contacts export PHP SDK

Tags: oauth-2.0, yahoo, yql, yahoo-api, yahoo-oauth

Hi I am using the yahoo php sdk for exporting the contacts.

As mentioned in the documentation I am changing all the api related details in common.inc.php

But when i go to any example it just gives a blank page.

Any help?

I've downloaded the sdk from here : http://developer.yahoo.com/social/sdk/#php

Regards,

Sushil

Answer (score 0):

If you run the above code in localhost then it wont work and it will show blank page.

So for that execute the code in your development or test server and it will execute fine.